# Is it normal to have an instant app apk bigger than the standard one?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

The standard one is 3.6 Mb (tested, it works) and the instant app 5.1 Mb.

I noticed that the instant app apk contains numerous dex files, is it normal ? This behaviour is, afaik, associated with the use of instant run but it is not supposed to happen with release apk creation (I used 'generate signed apk'), right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :

Minification and resconfigs were set in the normal and instant app gradle build files, it worked for the normal apk build but for not the instant app one.

I had to move them from the instant app config (minification and resconfigs) to the base feature one. For the normal apk, you have to let them in the apk build file.